# Probability distribution of $X^2$ given uniform distribution of $X$?

Tags: probability

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I'm going through a probability textbook and having a massive brainfart on one of the examples in the book.

The example/question in the book is straightforward:

A real number is chosen at random from $[0, 1]$ with uniform probability, and then this number is squared. Let $X$ represent the result. What is the cumulative distribution function of $X$? What is the density of $X$

The book lays out the solution as follows.

Let $U$ be the chosen number, then $X^2 = U$

$$F(x) = P\left(U^2 \le x\right)$$
$$F(x) = P(U \le\sqrt{x})$$

So far so good, I understand
$$=\sqrt{x}$$
I apologize, but for the life of me I cannot quite understand that last step. How do we just announce that the probability here is just $\sqrt{x}$? It might be plainly obvious but I just don't see it. What even does this statement say if we hold it to be true?

The probability that random variable $X$ will be less than $0.25$ is $0.5$ because $0.5^2 = 0.25$?

Comment: Sorry so how are you deriving the first part? $P(U≤u)=u$ ? Perhaps this the the part I'm so confused about. I feel as though it's something blindingly obvious and I'm just not at all seeing it

Comment: you are starting with  uniformly distributed random variable. All numbers are equally probable so the distribution function is a constant and the cumulative distribution is a ramp. With proper normalization in the interval [0,1] we get $F(x) = x$

Comment: I see. So the statement $P(U<=\sqrt{x})$ = $\sqrt{x}$ is true in this case only because the random variable is uniformly distributed?

Comment: Yes. To be precise "uniform in [0 1]". If it's uniform on, say, [0,2] we would get $F(x) = x/2$ and  $F(x^2)= \sqrt{x/2}$